# SSH access denied when 'authorized_keys' file is created with Vim

Tags: amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04, vim

I created an ec2 instance with an Ubuntu 16.04 AMI. I created a sudo user for this AMI with:

```
sudo adduser myuser
sudo usermod -aG sudo myuser
```

Then I attempted to give the user ssh access with an rsa keypair that I already had. I created an .ssh directory for the new user:

```
mkdir ~/.ssh
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
vim ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

I copied and pasted my public key into 'authorized_keys'. Then I exited ec2 and tested my connection with:

```
cd ~/.ssh
ssh -i "mypem.pem" myuser@ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

I got an error that read 'Access denied (public key)'

So I scrapped the user and created another user. This time a created the 'authorized_keys' file with nano instead of Vim and it worked.

Anyone experience this?

Comment: You didn't copy and paste it correctly, that is all.

Comment: It was copied an pasted correctly because I double checked it.

Comment: Your virtual machine disagrees with that assertion.

Comment: Maybe a couple of characters got clipped and I overlooked it. Thanks.

Comment: If you have `linebreak` activated in `vim` this can happen as the SSH key has to be one line. `linebreak` would insert a newlines and break the key.

Comment: Just do this again and store it in another file. Then use a diff tools to compare what's wrong.

Comment: Check `/var/log/secure`on the server you are trying to log into.

Answer (score 1):

If something like this happens, I would recommend tho check `fileencryption` , `fileformat` and `bomb` in ViM.
Compare both files, the one you edited with nano and the one you edited with vim. Open them with vim and check this:

`:set bomb?`
This is the byte order mark. Usually set when you edit a UTF-8 file with notepad.exe on windows. I often had problems with that.

`:set ff?`
Fileformat `dos` or `unix`. dos have different line endings than unix.

`:set fenc?`
The fileencoding: perhaps one editor changes to latin1 instead of UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you pasted it wrong.

- Does it start with `ssh-rsa` or with `ssh-ed25519`?
- Does it have a space before (it should NOT)
- Is upper/lower case preserved?
- is there a space before any comment at the end of the line?

before pasting anything in vim, you should use `:set paste`, as it switches off any possible active autocompletion/autoindent/... macros.

Another thing is, that you wrote `mykey.pem`, which is the usual extension for openssl files, not ssh-keys. Are you sure, you used the `id_rsa.pub` / `id_ed25519.pub` as ssh-pubkey?

Answer (score 0):

myuser must has access to .ssh and keyfile.
Check who owns them.

Comment: Given the information in the question this answer is most likely incorrect.